# How to properly append json result to a select option value

Tags: jquery, json, select

I am receiving the json format like

```
{
    "0": ["AL", "Alabama"],
    "9": ["FL", "Florida"]
}
```

I want to append this value in select box, option value lik

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>.
```

For that i tried the below code. It is appending the all values

```
success: function(json) {
    jQuery('#stateId').html('');
    jQuery.each(json, function(i, value) {
        jQuery('#stateId').append(jQuery('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
    });
}
```

Comment: `value[0]` for the value, and `value[1]` for the text

Comment: Its about dealing with dynamic/named indices of json..

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = {
    "0": ["AL", "Alabama"],
    "9": ["FL", "Florida"]
};

    jQuery('#stateId').html('');
    jQuery.each(json, function(i, value) {

    jQuery('#stateId').append(jQuery('<option>').text(value[1]).attr('value', value[0]));
    });
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/jbLLwg46/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(json) {
    jQuery('#stateId').html('');
    jQuery.each(json, function(i, value) {
        jQuery('#stateId').append(jQuery('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value[i]));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know bit more about json. Your json object is not an array. It contains multiple named (named as `0` , `1`) objects. Of those objects each is an array

So you have to loop over json to get each named index, then to get object at that index you have to use `jsonObject[index]` and not `jsonObject.index`

Now each of objects is an array of two items and you can use them as text and value like

```
for(var index in originalJson){
  var val = originalJson[index]; //it is same like originalJson.prop but     
  jQuery('#stateId').append('<option />').text(val[0]).attr('value',val[1]);
}
```

[**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SBcOVXAjP8n03697uNVt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

can also be done like this

```
d = {
    "0": ["AL", "Alabama"],
    "9": ["FL", "Florida"]
}
var str = "";
$.each(d, function(i,obj){
      str += "<option value='"+obj[0]+"'>"+obj[1]+"</option>";      
})
$("#selDropDown").html(str)
```